# mysql query - credit debit-> calculate balance (complex tables structure)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have this tables structure:

[image]

The "Plati" table = Credit.

The "Suma" column = amount.

Sample Debit Data:

[image]

Sample Credit Data:

[image]

And i want this result:

plati.Id 
debite.IdDosar 
debite.Suma 
plati.Suma AS Plata 
(debite.Suma - all previous plati.Suma order by plati.Data) AS RestPlata

Like This excel:

[image]

Is possible with sql query but not with variable, because i want to split this query's to create one view on finally?

Comment: This seems like a very strange way of implementing double-entry bookkeeping... it would be more normal to post both credits and debits to a single table (with the value's sign distinguishing between them).  One could then obtain the balance of an account simply by summing all entries posted to that account.

Comment: what tools you use for create table structure diagram (first your image).

Comment: @mehdilotfi MySQL Workbench: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: @TotPeRo. thanks for your answer. I locked for a tools for create beautifully diagram from sql server database.

Comment: @mehdilotfi Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio have this possibilities. Select your database and you find Database Diagrams.

Comment: you cant display your table indexes on SQL Server database diagram. and SQL Server diagrams not beautifully as your diagram.